# Library, third-party plugin for FMX FireMonkey Form Graph UI

Tags: ios, user-interface, graph, firemonkey

I am new to FMX forms and have made a simple health monitoring UI app for iOS. I would like to show the user data over a period of some time in a bar chart form, which would look appealing also. I do want the grid lines behind the bar chart and would like to make it more flat, not 3D.

Are there any exiting third party plugins or library API that I can use in my application? I would be willing to buy a license for it too.

An example bar chart would be something similar to the default in-built iOS app for health monitoring - healthkit.

[image]

Another option would be [such](https://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2015/02/the-best-free-ui-kits-february-2015/) UI kits, would these be available for integrating with FMX?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Regards,
Yusuf Husainy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked out the TChart component that comes with Delphi? There is also a pro version that has more capabilities. Check out https://www.steema.com/product/vcl (the URL says "vcl" but TChart is available for Firemonkey too). You should be able to make charts like the ones you want with it.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I needed.